# What is the "definition" tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [definition](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) tag has currently 8 questions, and I have no idea what this tag is for. Ironically, this tag has no definition. So what is this tag for?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all but two of the 8 questions are about muscle definition with the outlier being an off-topic dietary question about [why milk isn't "vegan"](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/25554/why-milk-is-not-vegan) and one about the term ["conditioner" when used referring to swimming](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18177/what-does-it-mean-to-condition-the-body). I was confused at first, because one seemed to be about the definition of different "high intensity" workouts, however, clicking through, the querent keeps referring to how their primary concern is muscle definition.

I removed `definition` off of the first two, and replaced it with `terminology`, which is at least used in one other place. I then added a definition indicating the tag is for muscle definition, although it's apparently in the editing queue.

Answer (score 0):

On Stack Overflow, [definition](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) is for the definition of terms, like "what is currying?" The tag we have should be changed to [muscle-definition](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muscle-definition).

Comment: That looks to be what [tag:terminology] is fulfilling for us so far, although I suppose we could rename one, then the other.

Comment: On Stack Overflow you see "terminology" in questions of the form "What do you call it when you...?" I think that makes sense.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - Noumenon is correct, terminology is things like supination, abduction, adduction. Terminology encompasses the particular jargon of an area of study. Adduction is a term, that has a definition. I'd agree also with changing the current tag to "muscle-definition"

Comment: Well, if we have a standard, I guess we'd best follow it. As I understand it, now we need a moderator. Either that, or we just retag it all.